# Using Named Group Capture With rex In a Splunk Dashboard Query?

Tags: splunk

While trying to use `rex` as part of a splunk search I have a regular expression that works fine:

```
eventtype=my_type | rex field=_raw ".*\[(?<foo>.*?)\].*" | table _time, foo
```

But when I try to save the search into a dashboard table I get the following error:

> Error parsing XML on line 29: Premature end of data in tag form line 1

I know my query is fine because when I click the "Run Search" button while adding it to the dashboard table I get a valid result.  But when I click the save button I get the above error.

I suspect the named group capture within the `regular expression` is throwing off the `XML` parser.

**How do I use a rex regular expression with name capture as part of a dashboard query?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use named group capture you have to replace the angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
... | rex field=_raw ".*\[(?&lt;foo&gt;.*?)\].*" | ...
```